# How can I generate truncated normal draws from truncated standard normal draws?

Tags: simulation, truncated-normal-distribution

Some random variables are transformations of a standard normal. For example, a draw from a normal density with mean $b$ and variance $s^2$ is obtained as$$e = b + s\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon$ is a draw of a standard normal.

I have a model and I estimate various parameters of the model using the maximum likelihood principle in MATLAB. I obtain draws from the truncated standard normal using a random number genertor in MATLAB. What I want to do is to obtain truncated normal draws using the already generated truncated standard normal draws.

1. If $\upsilon$ is a draw from truncated standard normal, can I calculate$$e = b + s\upsilon$$ to obtain a draw from truncated normal density?
2. Can I define $b$ and $s$ as parameters to be estimated in my maximum likelihood procedure so that I do not need to calculate them analytically beforehand?

Comment: Thank you very much for the edits.

Comment: I guess using e in both equations is confusing. I propose to change the second e to another letter.

Comment: But then edit the post yourself!

Comment: Well, no because then the notation in the given answer should change too. Then future readers will be totally confused. It would be great if Xi'an could do this. So the second e should change to another letter. Also, b and s should change I guess because the mean and standard deviation I suppose will be different after truncating the standard normal?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty with the change in location and scale in the transform
$$e = b + s\upsilon$$is that, if $\upsilon$ is a truncated standard random variable restricted to the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$ then $e$ is a truncated non-standard random variable restricted to the interval $(b+s\alpha,b+s\beta)$. In other words, the truncated Normal distribution is a four parameter family rather than two.

Hence, if the target is a truncated $\mathcal N(b,s^2)$ distribution restricted to the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$, the indentity
\begin{align}\mathbb P(e\le x)&=\mathbb P(e-b\le x-b)\\
&=\mathbb P(\underbrace{s^{-1}\{e-b\}}_\text{truncated $\mathcal N(0,1)$}\le s^{-1}\{x-b\})\\
&=\dfrac{\Phi(s^{-1}\{x-b\})-\Phi(s^{-1}\{\alpha-b\})}
{\Phi(s^{-1}\{\beta-b\})-\Phi(s^{-1}\{\alpha-b\})}\\
\end{align}
This shows that the truncated standard normal must be restricted to the interval
$$(s^{-1}\{\alpha-b\},s^{-1}\{\beta-b\})$$

In conclusion,

> to simulate a truncated $\mathcal N(b,s^2)$ distribution restricted to
> the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$,
>
> 1. Generate a truncated standard normal $X$ restricted to the interval $(s^{-1}\{\alpha-b\},s^{-1}\{\beta-b\})$
> 2. Apply the transform $Y=b+sX$

Comment: How can I transform the truncated standard normal to truncated normal then?

Comment: By the location-scale transformation, as indicated.